# How to assign char to string object in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char, toupper

i am trying to convert the string into capital letter string by assigning single char's to string like this:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string a;
  getline(cin,a);
  string b;
  b.reserve(a.size()+1);
  for(int i=(a.size()),i1=0;1;i1++)
  {
    if(b[i1]!='\0')
        b[i1]=(char)toupper(a[i1]);
    else
    {
        a[i1]='\0';
        break;
    }
  }
  cout << b <<endl;
}
```

every when run `a.out` by ./a.out ,Only `endl` gets prints

here is sample run:-

```
$ ./a.out 
play clash royale

$
```

What is wrong in my program?? How can I assign single char to string??

Comment: Test `a` and assign `b`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet means ???

Comment: try to display after reversing the string( `cout << b <<endl;`). Then if it works check loop and condition

Comment: Whats this weird `int i=(a.size()),i1=0` thing all about? You don't even use `i`.

Comment: `b` is an empty string, even after `reserve()` call. `b.size() == 0` still. Therefore, `b[i1]` is a buffer overrun for any value of `i1`. Your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @Blasanka `int i=(a.size()),i1=0` was to control loop but i don't use itInsted I have used `break`.It was left there as useless expression that I forgot to remove. sorry.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So is there any solution??

Comment: See @Amadeus answer. If you ran this in a debugger, i am pretty sure you would have found the issue.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What is debugger ??

Comment: A debugger is something you can google instead of opening a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues with your program. The main one is probably the diference between [string reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) and [string resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize). What you want in your program is already had a string of `a.size()` length, so, use `b.resize(a.size())`.

A working version is bellow (there are better ways to write this, just being most consistent with OP proposal):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string a;
   getline(cin,a);
   string b;
   b.resize(a.size());
   for(int i1=0; i1 < a.size();i1++)
   {
      if(a[i1]!='\0')
          b[i1]=(char)toupper(a[i1]);
      else
      {
          b[i1]='\0';
          break;
      }
   }
   cout << b <<endl;
}
```

Comment: If using C++11, you can just do: `for(char chA: a){...}` and replace all the `a[i1]` in the loop by `chA`

Comment: @Tuan333 I would use `std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ::toupper);` to an implace conversion or `std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(),b.begin(), ::toupper);` to put in b

Comment: True. I thought we are just modifying the source code of OP, so I thought I would chip in some comments to make it more modern :P

Comment: @Tuan333 So is there any other modern way?? Please Can you tell me that ?? I am new to c++